# Separating data frame using row indices

Tags: r

I am currently trying to separate a data frame into smaller blocks based on headers, that are currently also listed as individual rows, like this:

```
1                 >904 5.000000e+00         <NA>         <NA>
2     0.00961538461538 9.615385e-03 9.615385e-03 9.711538e-01
3     0.00961538461538 9.615385e-03 9.711538e-01 9.615385e-03
4     0.00961538461538 9.615385e-03 9.711538e-01 9.615385e-03
5     0.00961538461538 9.615385e-03 9.711538e-01 9.615385e-03
6       0.971153846154 9.615385e-03 9.615385e-03 9.615385e-03
7                 >s36 7.000000e+00         <NA>         <NA>
8       0.844325153374 7.668712e-04 1.541411e-01 7.668712e-04
9      0.0774539877301 6.909509e-01 7.745399e-02 1.541411e-01
10   0.000766871165644 7.745399e-02 1.541411e-01 7.676380e-01
11       0.76763803681 7.745399e-02 7.668712e-04 1.541411e-01
12     0.0774539877301 7.745399e-02 7.676380e-01 7.745399e-02
13      0.230828220859 6.142638e-01 7.745399e-02 7.745399e-02
14      0.460889570552 2.308282e-01 1.541411e-01 1.541411e-01
```

Headers are the ">" rows and the numbers below are matrices that I want as values for the headers.

I would like it to look like this:

```
$0
1                 >904 5.000000e+00         <NA>         <NA>
2     0.00961538461538 9.615385e-03 9.615385e-03 9.711538e-01
3     0.00961538461538 9.615385e-03 9.711538e-01 9.615385e-03
4     0.00961538461538 9.615385e-03 9.711538e-01 9.615385e-03
5     0.00961538461538 9.615385e-03 9.711538e-01 9.615385e-03
6       0.971153846154 9.615385e-03 9.615385e-03 9.615385e-03

$1
7                 >s36 7.000000e+00         <NA>         <NA>
8       0.844325153374 7.668712e-04 1.541411e-01 7.668712e-04
9      0.0774539877301 6.909509e-01 7.745399e-02 1.541411e-01
10   0.000766871165644 7.745399e-02 1.541411e-01 7.676380e-01
11       0.76763803681 7.745399e-02 7.668712e-04 1.541411e-01
12     0.0774539877301 7.745399e-02 7.676380e-01 7.745399e-02
13      0.230828220859 6.142638e-01 7.745399e-02 7.745399e-02
14      0.460889570552 2.308282e-01 1.541411e-01 1.541411e-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `split`:

```r
split(df, cumsum(grepl("^>", df[[1]])))

$`1`
                V2          V3           V4           V5
1             >904 5.000000000         <NA>         <NA>
2 0.00961538461538 0.009615385 9.615385e-03 9.711538e-01
3 0.00961538461538 0.009615385 9.711538e-01 9.615385e-03
4 0.00961538461538 0.009615385 9.711538e-01 9.615385e-03
5 0.00961538461538 0.009615385 9.711538e-01 9.615385e-03
6   0.971153846154 0.009615385 9.615385e-03 9.615385e-03

$`2`
                  V2           V3           V4           V5
7               >s36 7.0000000000         <NA>         <NA>
8     0.844325153374 0.0007668712 1.541411e-01 7.668712e-04
9    0.0774539877301 0.6909509000 7.745399e-02 1.541411e-01
10 0.000766871165644 0.0774539900 1.541411e-01 7.676380e-01
11     0.76763803681 0.0774539900 7.668712e-04 1.541411e-01
12   0.0774539877301 0.0774539900 7.676380e-01 7.745399e-02
13    0.230828220859 0.6142638000 7.745399e-02 7.745399e-02
14    0.460889570552 0.2308282000 1.541411e-01 1.541411e-01
```

---

Data:

```r
df <- structure(list(V2 = c(">904", "0.00961538461538", "0.00961538461538", 
"0.00961538461538", "0.00961538461538", "0.971153846154", ">s36", 
"0.844325153374", "0.0774539877301", "0.000766871165644", "0.76763803681", 
"0.0774539877301", "0.230828220859", "0.460889570552"), V3 = c(5, 
0.009615385, 0.009615385, 0.009615385, 0.009615385, 0.009615385, 
7, 0.0007668712, 0.6909509, 0.07745399, 0.07745399, 0.07745399, 
0.6142638, 0.2308282), V4 = c("<NA>", "9.615385e-03", "9.711538e-01", 
"9.711538e-01", "9.711538e-01", "9.615385e-03", "<NA>", "1.541411e-01", 
"7.745399e-02", "1.541411e-01", "7.668712e-04", "7.676380e-01", 
"7.745399e-02", "1.541411e-01"), V5 = c("<NA>", "9.711538e-01", 
"9.615385e-03", "9.615385e-03", "9.615385e-03", "9.615385e-03", 
"<NA>", "7.668712e-04", "1.541411e-01", "7.676380e-01", "1.541411e-01", 
"7.745399e-02", "7.745399e-02", "1.541411e-01")), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Wow! This answer is just perfect! Can you please explain what ```cumsum``` does in this case?

Comment: grepl finds items that starts with `>` in the first column. cumsum does a cumulative sum everytime there is a TRUE